# Replace values based on a list but keep replaced value on a separate colum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like the following

```
ColumnA
"ABC X1"
"BCS X2"
"CCC X3"
```

And i would like to replace part of the strings with "" based if they are on a list, but also keep them in a separate column. Say my list is for example;

```
["X1","X3"]
```

So my  desired output would be

```
ColumnA     ColumnB 
"ABC"       "X1"
"BCS X2"    
"CCC"       "X3"
```

I know how to replace values values using `replace` and i also think i could get to the solution by using a for loop and comparing each value to the values on the list and keeping them if they match, but maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it twice:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df.ColumnA.str.extract(f'({"|".join(strs)})')[0]
df['ColumnA'] =df.ColumnA.replace(strs,'', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
0    ABC       X1
1  BCS X2     NaN
2    CCC       X3
```

Comment: `df.ColumnA.str.extract(f'({"|".join(strs)})').squeeze()` may be more readable and conveying IMO.

Comment: `df.ColumnA.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(strs)})').unstack(-1)` if multiple matches are expected.

Comment: Thanks! I did have multiple matches so i used @r.rook approach. Used `df.ColumnA.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(strs)})').unstack(-1).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1] `  to keep the last match.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ["X1","X3"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ["ABC X1", "BCS X2", "CCC X3"]})

import re

r = re.compile('|'.join(r'(\b{}\b)'.format(re.escape(v)) for v in lst))

df = df.ColumnA.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v.strip() for v in r.split(x) if v])) \
               .rename(columns={0:'ColumnA', 1:'ColumnB'}) \
               .fillna('')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     ABC      X1
1  BCS X2        
2     CCC      X3
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach with `split` and `isin`:

```
l = ["X1","X3"]

s = df.pop("ColumnA").str.strip('"')
df[['ColumnA','ColumnB']] = s.str.split(expand=True).where(lambda x: x[1].isin(l))
df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].fillna(s)
```

---

```
print(df)

  ColumnA ColumnB
0     ABC      X1
1  BCS X2     NaN
2     CCC      X3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` by a white space if followed by any element of the list, catch with using the Positive lookahead regex expression `(?=`

```
l = ["X1","X3"]
c = '|'.join(l)
df_ = (df['ColumnA'].str.split(f' (?={c})', expand=True)
                    .rename(columns={0:'ColumnA', 1:'ColumnB'})
                    .fillna(''))
print (df_)
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     ABC      X1
1  BCS X2        
2     CCC      X3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def match(_):
    for m in match_lst:
        if m in _:
            return ','.join(_.split())
    return f"{_},"

df = df['ColumnA'].apply(match).str.split(',', 1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's find the rows which we have to modify:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ["ABC X1", "BCS X2", "CCC X3"]})
values = ["X1","X3"]

columns_to_modify = df['ColumnA'].str.contains('|'.join(values))
```

Then we create a ColumnB with empty strings:

```
df['ColumnB'] = ''
```

And split only the rows which we have to modify onto the new column:

```
df[columns_to_modify] = df['ColumnA'].str.split(expand=True)[columns_to_modify]
```

output:

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     ABC      X1
1  BCS X2        
2     CCC      X3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way about it:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')

mapping = ["X1","X3"]

#create a search based on the mapping
regex_pattern = re.compile(fr"{'|'.join(mapping)}\Z")

#iterate through column A to get matches 
#and if no matches return None
outcome = [(entry,rada.group()  
            if (rada := regex_pattern.search(entry)) else None) 
            for entry in df.ColumnA]

df.ColumnA, df["ColumnB"] = zip(*outcome)



    ColumnA ColumnB
0   ABC X1  X1
1   BCS X2  None
2   CCC X3  X3
```

Shorter syntax with Pandas string functions though